# unable to write tuple into xslx file using python without pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel

I am trying to write the output into xslx file, but able to only write the headers not able to write the data below headers.

```
import xlsxwriter

csv_columns = (
    'id', 'name', 'place', 'salary', 'email',
)
details = [{'id':1, 'name': 'A', 'place':'B', 'salary': 2, 'email': 'c@d.com'}, 
          {'id':3, 'name':'C', 'place':'D', 'salary': 4, 'email':'e@f.com'}]

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(path)
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

for col, name in enumerate(csv_columns):
    worksheet.write(0, col, name)

for row, det in enumerate(details, 1):
    for col, value in enumerate(det):
        worksheet.write(row, col, value)

workbook.close()
```

This code is only writing the csv_columns in xslx file and repeating same in all rows as below

```
id  name    place   salary  email
id  name    place   salary  email
id  name    place   salary  email
```

How to solve this issue of repeating columns in xslx? any help ?

I expected like below:

```
  id    name    place   salary  email
  1    A         B       2       c@d.com
  3    C         D       4       e@f.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
from openpyxl import Workbook
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

csv_columns = (
    'id', 'name', 'place', 'salary', 'email',
)
details = [{'id':1, 'name': 'A', 'place':'B', 'salary': 2, 'email': 'c@d.com'},
          {'id':3, 'name':'C', 'place':'D', 'salary': 4, 'email':'e@f.com'}]


details_values = [tuple(d.values()) for d in details]
details_values.insert(0, csv_columns)

for row in details_values:
    print(row)
    ws.append(row)

wb.save(output_file_path)
```

Answer (score 1):

I corrected your code. Now it works as you would expect:

```
import xlsxwriter

csv_columns = (
    'id', 'name', 'place', 'salary', 'email',
)
values = [(1, 'A', 'B', 2, 'c@d.com'), 
          (3, 'C', 'D', 4, 'e@f.com')]

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(path)
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

row, col = 0, 0
worksheet.write_row(row, col, csv_columns)
row += 1

for value in values:
    worksheet.write_row(row, col, value)
    row += 1

workbook.close()
```

Comment: Thanks! , but you have changed the values which I am getting from DB that cannot be changed. the values will be 'Id' :1 so this code is not helping me

Answer (score 1):

It would probably be best to map your dictionaries into a list of lists and then process it that way, but here is one way of doing it based on your sample code:

```py
import xlsxwriter

csv_columns = ('id', 'name', 'place', 'salary', 'email')
details = [{'id': 1, 'name': 'A', 'place': 'B', 'salary': 2, 'email': 'c@d.com'},
           {'id': 3, 'name': 'C', 'place': 'D', 'salary': 4, 'email': 'e@f.com'}]

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook("test.xlsx")
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

worksheet.write_row(0, 0, csv_columns)

for row, det in enumerate(details, 1):
    for col, key in enumerate(csv_columns):
        worksheet.write(row, col, det.get(key, ''))

workbook.close()
```

Output:

[image]